# Hibernate return auto-generate id of a newly inserted row

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring

I'm using HibernateTemplate to access the database in my Spring application.
Is there any way/method in HibernateTemplate which returns the auto-generate id
for my new inserted row? In my case, the auto-generate value is the primary key of my table, which is defined as auto-increment inside the database.

For more info, I use saveOrUpdate() method to insert data.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you save a object with `saveOrUpdate()` the objects `id` field will get updated with the auto generated `id` if it was a create operation. So you can simply retrieve the `id` property of the saved object to get the auto generated id.

Comment: Could you extend your answer to say how it is carried out in MySQL?
I can't see any select LAST_INSERT_ID() in the profiler (when I connect to SQL Server I see scope_identity()).

Comment: Object object = new Object;
// object.getId() == null
saveOrUpdate(object);
object.getId() == inserted id